# Is it possible to have gitlab ci input variables based on selection from previous dropdown value?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to add env specific variables to gitlab ci.

For example: I have variable called targetenv in the Variable section in .gitlabci.yml and I have put three values in options. code should look like below.

```
  target_env:
    value: "dev"
    options:
      - "dev"
      - "ppe"
      - "prod"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhVg5.png)

Now based on selection user choose from dropdown, some more inputs should appear such as dev_server or prod_server.

How is it possible in Gitlab CI?

In official gitlab documentation I could not find about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a feature available in GitLab today. However, there is an open [feature ticket](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/351067) that would implement this feature.